# How to send a push notification to more than one device (iOS)?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I'm trying to optimize the push notifications on my server. For now I send those one by one (with an old library) and it takes a while (4 hours).

I refactored my service to send a notification with a lot of device tokens (For now I tried with batches of 500 tokens). For that I'm using the [Redth/PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) library. I followed the [sample code](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Sample/Program.cs) then I adapted it to send the notifications to severals device tokens.

```
PushService service = new PushService();

//Wire up the events
service.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionExpired(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired);
service.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged);
service.Events.OnChannelException += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelExceptionDelegate(Events_OnChannelException);
service.Events.OnNotificationSendFailure += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.NotificationSendFailureDelegate(Events_OnNotificationSendFailure);
service.Events.OnNotificationSent += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.NotificationSentDelegate(Events_OnNotificationSent);
service.Events.OnChannelCreated += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelCreatedDelegate(Events_OnChannelCreated);
service.Events.OnChannelDestroyed += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.ChannelDestroyedDelegate(Events_OnChannelDestroyed);

//Configure and start ApplePushNotificationService
string p12Filename = ...
string p12FilePassword = ...

var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(p12Filename);

service.StartApplePushService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCert, p12FilePassword));

var appleNotification = NotificationFactory.Apple();

foreach (var itemToProcess in itemsToProcess)
{
    itemToProcess.NotificationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    mobile.SubmitChanges();

    string deviceToken = GetCleanDeviceToken(itemToProcess.MobileDevice.PushNotificationIdentifier);
    appleNotification.ForDeviceToken(deviceToken);
}

service.QueueNotification(appleNotification
    .WithAlert(itemsToProcess[0].MobileDeviceNotificationText.Text)
    .WithSound("default")
    .WithBadge(0)
    .WithCustomItem("View", itemsToProcess[0].Value.ToString()));

//Stop and wait for the queues to drains
service.StopAllServices(true);
```

Then I tried to send 3 notifications to 2 devices. Only the first device got them (and the problem is not device-related because I tried with both of them separately).
Right after that an OperationCanceledException is thrown in the [PushChannelBase class](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Common/PushChannelBase.cs). So I don't know what's wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Hi. This is possible to send single push messages to multiple devices in single request. I did the r&d and implement the code ready and tested with 5-10 devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should queue a separate notification for each item to process.
It is not possible set multiple device tokens on a single notification. The OperationCanceledException will occur, because you do.

Comment: Hi. This is possible to send single push messages to multiple devices in single request. I did the r&d and implement the code ready and tested with 5-10 devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Example: Console C# Application**

This assumes

1. you have valid production and development certificates
2. you have stored multiple device tokens within your database
3. you have a notification that comes from your database
4. You are using [PushSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp/) Library

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using PushSharp;
   using PushSharp.Core;
   using PushSharp.Apple;
   using System.IO;

   namespace MyNotification
   {
       class Program
       {
           //args may take "true" or "false" to indicate the app is running for
           //development or production (Default = false which means Development)
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               bool isProduction = false;
               if (args != null && args.Length == 1)
               {
                   Console.Write(args[0] + Environment.NewLine);
                   bool.TryParse(args[0], out isProduction);
               }
               try
               {
                   //Gets a notification that needs sending from database
                   AppNotification notification = AppNotification.GetNotification();
                   if (notification != null && notification.ID > 0)
                   {          
                       //Gets all devices to send the above notification to         
                       List<IosDevice> devices = IosDevice.GetDevices(!isProduction);
                       if (devices != null && devices.Count > 0)
                       {
                           PushBroker push = new PushBroker();//a single instance per app
                           //Wire up the events for all the services that the broker registers
                           push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
                           push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
                           push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
                           push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
                           push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
                           push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
                           push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;
                           //make sure your certifcates path are all good  
                           string apnsCertFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../Certificate/Certificates_Apple_Push_Production.p12");
                           if (!isProduction)
                               apnsCertFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../Certificate/Certificates_Apple_Push_Development.p12");
                           var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(apnsCertFile);
                           push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(isProduction, appleCert, "135TrID35")); //Extension method

                           foreach (IosDevice device in devices)
                           {
                               //if it is required to send additional information as well as the alert message, uncomment objects[] and WithCustomItem 
                               //object[] obj = { "North", "5" };

                               push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                              .ForDeviceToken(device.DeviceToken)
                              .WithAlert(DateTime.Now.ToString())//(notification.AlertMessage)
                                   //.WithCustomItem("Link", obj)
                              .WithBadge(device.BadgeCount + 1)
                              .WithSound(notification.SoundFile));//sound.caf
                           }
                           push.StopAllServices(waitForQueuesToFinish: true);
                       }
                   }
                   Console.WriteLine("Queue Finished, press return to exit...");
                   Console.ReadLine();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                   Console.ReadLine();
               }
           }

           static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + sender + " -> " + notification);
           }

           static void NotificationFailed(object sender, INotification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + sender + " -> " + notificationFailureException.Message + " -> " + notification);
           }

           static void ChannelException(object sender, IPushChannel channel, Exception exception)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Channel Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
           }

           static void ServiceException(object sender, Exception exception)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Service Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
           }

           static void DeviceSubscriptionExpired(object sender, string expiredDeviceSubscriptionId, DateTime timestamp, INotification notification)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Device Subscription Expired: " + sender + " -> " + expiredDeviceSubscriptionId);
           }

           static void ChannelDestroyed(object sender)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Channel Destroyed for: " + sender);
           }

           static void ChannelCreated(object sender, IPushChannel pushChannel)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Channel Created for: " + sender);
           }  
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: is there a way to send a push notification to several devices without a for each loop? such as a bulk push ? all at once..

Comment: this does a bulk push, the for each loop is just to add devices to the push queue. i am using this on production and works like a charm :)

Comment: Hi. This is possible to send single push messages to multiple devices in single request. I did the r&d and implement the code ready and tested with 5-10 devices.

Comment: @V.J. can you explain how you did it? As by now (July 2021) there is no known interface towards APNS. Explain how you did it (without using some kind of loops).